# Layout of three Young diagram

Tags: spacing, vertical-alignment, positioning, diagrams

I am trying to let these three diagrams more neat. Like, (1,1,1),(2,1),(3) are lying on the same line, and the arrows all point the middle of Young diagram. Anyone could help me?[image]

My code is:

Example: Partition of 3

```
\begin{multicols}{3}
\noindent
$(1,1,1)\longleftrightarrow$ $\begin{Young}
\cr
\cr
\cr
\end{Young}$
$(2,1)\longleftrightarrow$ $\begin{Young}
&\cr
\cr
\end{Young}$
$(3)\longleftrightarrow$ $\begin{Young}
&&\cr
\end{Young}$
\end{multicols}
```

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would consider using a different package for your Young diagrams, namely `youngtab`, the vertical centering of the diagrams on the line is easy. You just need to load the package with the `vcentermath` option.

The slightly jumbled appearance you show come from using the `multicols` environment. I don't know why you have that, seems to me that a single display math environment (`\[ ... \]`) makes more sense here.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[vcentermath]{youngtab}
\begin{document}
\[
(1,1,1)\longleftrightarrow\;
\yng(1,1,1)\qquad
(2,1)\longleftrightarrow\;
\yng(2,1)\qquad
(3)\longleftrightarrow\;
\yng(3)
\]
\end{document}
```